# How to find the count of exact word "xyZ" from x.txt file

Tags: bash, text-processing

My trying approach :

```
 { head -n 10 x.txt | grep -ow 'xyZ' && tail -n 10 y.txt
```

```
x.txt
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Obviously your code snippet uses other file names and search patterns than you require in your explanation. Please [edit] your question and make sure the code matches the explanation. Show the (example) content of your input files, the actual output of your script and the expected output matching the example input.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework. I won't give you an exact answer, instead some hints:

1. store the output of `head -n 10 pptxt.txt | grep -ow 'abC' | wc -w` in a variable ([3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution))
2. do the same with the other 2 files
3. add the numbers ([Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)
   and [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic))